# Adobe AIr for IOS-programmatically quit

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

The following SHOULD exit and quit my application but is not working. Anyone have any ideas?

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `import flash.system.fscommand`

Then use: `fscommand( "quit" )`

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, you can't quit an application using a function call. From the [AS3 API reference for `NativeApplication.exit`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html#exit%28%29):

> Note: This method is not supported on the iOS operating system.

It's how iOS works; no apps have quit functionality. iOS itself will decide when to terminate your app,

Comment: according to this thread(see post 13) I assumed it WAS possible http://forums.adobe.com/thread/870733

Comment: That post is about quit on suspend, your app will only quit when the app is suspended by the user. That means when the user switches apps, or presses home. Not really what you asked I think.